# Can I upgrade my Ubuntu 10.04 to 10.10 using LiveCD?

Tags: upgrade, live-cd

Can I upgrade my Ubuntu with a LiveCD (I don't have a stable internet connection)? If I have to use the command line please provide a step-by-step solution as I'm a beginner.

And I heard, many problem after upgrade to ubuntu 10.10? Is it true?

Answer (score 4):

You can upgrade from the Alternate CD, not the Live CD.

This is because the Live CD is basically an install of Ubuntu squeezed onto a disk with a apt database while the Alternate CD is just full of raw packages and you need the packages to upgrade.

But if you have things that aren't in the default install on your install, they won't be able to be upgraded without an internet connection anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Generally everything works fine. Here u have how to upgrade using CD/DVD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaverickUpgrades

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not recommend an upgrade from a LTS to 10.10. Of course you can do it using the alternate CD, but you will be better off by running a fresh install.

Comment: Could you justify why you wouldn't recommend upgrading?

Comment: Dont get me wrong. I have been using ubuntu for the past 3 years or so and i have always upgraded. but the upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10 was not as smooth as i expected. broken apps,resolution problems etc etc. Being somewhat experienced I fixed most of the problems myself ( Thanks to stack exchange of ofcourse ). As the user himself states that he is a beginner he might not be so inclined. Then Again it is strictly a personal opinion and no offence meant to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert the CD and start normal install and format the **/root** only - -- Dev